# Python - sphinx_rtd_theme - Change theme used in static website

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I've been playing around with SQLLineage https://github.com/reata/sqllineage
I'm looking to change so the white writing on purple is white writing on a black bar and the DAGs are white dots on black background.

I've tried adding a custom css in the static folder and referenced that in the conf.py.
`html_css_files = ['custom.css']`
Nothing changed.

I've also tried adding in the html_theme_options
`html_theme_options = {'bgcolor': 'Black', ...}`

I've tried adding a logo as well using the following to test html_theme_options, but nothing is passing through.
`html_theme_options = {'html_logo': 'a.png'}`

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Check your rendered built files to see whether the static assets are referenced and use the browser's developer tools to determine whether the static asset is not found.

Comment: Hi - The static files it references when I look using developer tools are different "Main.SomeNumbers.css" - in this file the colors referenced aren't the colors that are displayed though.